# Error creating hardcoded dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

Trying to create a hard-coded dataset for an SSRS report for months in the quarter.  I have this:

```
SELECT CASE @Quarter
  WHEN 'Q1' THEN (
    SELECT 'January' as months, '01' as month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'February','02' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'March', '03')
  WHEN 'Q2' THEN (
    SELECT 'April' as months, '04' as month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May','05' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'June', '06')
  WHEN 'Q3' THEN (
    SELECT 'July' as months, '07' as month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'August','08' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'September', '09')
  ELSE (
    SELECT 'October' as months, '10' as month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'November','11' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'December', '12')
END
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Previously I tried using a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Months TABLE (months VARCHAR(9), month_start VARCHAR(2));

IF @Quarter = 'Q1' 
  INSERT INTO @Months VALUES ('January','01'), ('February','02'), ('March','03')
ELSE IF @Quarter = 'Q2'
  INSERT INTO @Months VALUES ('April','04'), ('May','05'), ('June','06')
ELSE IF @Quarter = 'Q3'
  INSERT INTO @Months VALUES ('July','07'), ('August','08'), ('September','09')
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @Months VALUES ('October','10'), ('November','11'), ('December','12')

Select * FROM @Months
```

But I then get the error:

> The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get it working within an SSRS Dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

```
Declare @Quarter varchar(2) = 'Q1'

Select months,month_number From (Values 
('01','January','Q1'),('02','February','Q1'),('03','March','Q1'),
('04','April','Q2'),('05','May','Q2'),('06','June','Q2'),
('07','July','Q3'),('08','August','Q3'),('09','September','Q3'),
('10','October','Q4'),('11','November','Q4'),('12','December','Q4')
) N(month_number,months,Qtr)
Where Qtr=@Quarter
```

Returns

```
Months   Month_Number
January  01
February 02
March    03
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for a way to prototype a report without creating a db table with data in it.  Your method works really well !!

Comment: @ripvlan Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a CTE with all months and quarters.

```
WITH MONTHS AS (
SELECT 'January' as months, '01' as month_number, 'Q1' [quarter]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'February','02', 'Q1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'March', '03', 'Q1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'April' as months, '04' as month_number, 'Q2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'May','05', 'Q2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'June', '06', 'Q2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'July' as months, '07' as month_number, 'Q3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'August','08', 'Q3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'September', '09', 'Q3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'October' as months, '10' as month_number, 'Q4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'November','11', 'Q4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'December', '12', 'Q4')
SELECT * FROM MONTHS
WHERE [quarter] = @Quarter
```

Let me know if this helps.